# Pass filename from find and execute command

Tags: command-line, find, osx, java

I'm trying to write a script which finds certain files and executes a command with the files it finds. Doesn't sound too hard, but I'm having a lot of trouble getting it to work. Basically this is what I'm doing:

```
find /Users/Me/MyFolder -name '*filename.tsv' -print0 -exec /usr/bin/java -jar -Xmx2G /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Applications/mMyApp/MyApp.jar -s "," -e "." {}  > {}-new.tsv \;
```

The result is a file called `{}-new.tsv` which contains the output of MyApp.jar for all files that are found.

Can anyone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How about if you enclose the `-exec` statement like this: `-exec '/usr/bin/java -jar -Xmx2G /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Applications/mMyApp/MyApp.jar -s "," -e "." {}  > {}-new.tsv' \;`

Comment: @nwilder I tried that, but for some reason this results in a "No such file or directory" error..

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=find+redirection+exec

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved it. Apparently the braces have to be masked:

```
find /Users/Me/MyFolder -name '*filename.tsv' -print0 -exec bash -c '/usr/bin/java -jar -Xmx2G /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Applications/mMyApp/MyApp.jar -s "," -e "." "$1"  > "$1-new.tsv"' {} \;
```

Furthermore, the command has to be invoked by using `bash -c 'command string'` (make sure to escape single quotes)

Comment: I think you'd want to drop the backslashes in front of the `"`s as otherwise they'd been passed literally to `java` which I don't think is intended.

Comment: Note that you don't need to use `bash`. `sh` will do just as well.

Comment: Also note that that `$0` is also used for error messages, a more idiomatic way to write it is `-exec sh -c '... "$1"' sh {} \;` or to avoid running so many `sh` commands: `-exec sh -c 'for file do; ... "$file"; done' sh {} +`.